# How to get same result for same data with RSA encryption

Tags: c#, encryption

I need an asymmetric encryption algorith which always encrypts the data with same result for same data. When I use `RSACryptoServiceProvider` it is always giving me different encrypted data for same input.

```
byte[] encrypted1, encrypted2; 

using ( var RSA1 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider() )
{    
    encrypted1 = RSA1.Encrypt(data, false);
    encrypted2 = RSA1.Encrypt(data, false); 
}
```

Here `encrypted1` and `encrypted2`are different.

I heard this is caused by the random padding ability of new RSA implementation. But it happens even if I set padding to the false. So;

1. Is there any way to change this behavior?
2. Are there any other algorithms for this job? If there are what are them?

Comment: But why do you want repeat the encryption? Encryption algiritms are normally designed to ensure that you get the plain text when you decrypt the ciphered data. If you wanted to compare things like whether password matches, etc, you could use hash algorithms like MD5, etc.

Comment: hmm let me think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean you are referring to is not meant to switch the padding on or off. It uses OAEP padding or PKCS#1 v1.5 padding (it should never have been a boolean in the first place, it should have been an enum value). Both padding mechanisms deploy (partially) randomized padding. As long as your random source is indeed random, the output won't be *deterministic*.

You can of course create your own padding, e.g. using the `BlindedRSAEngine` of Bouncy Castle, but if you remove the random padding, you invalidate the security of RSA. Only do this if you fully understand the implications, as for instance indicated [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1832/1172).

In other words: don't go there.